# Gettng "Cannot Open FIle" error while using phpBetter vs code extension

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit

Actually am trying to setup phpbetter unit extension in my vscode but am getting following error while running my test cases.

```
 *  Executing task: ./vendor/bin/sail php vendor/bin/phpunit /home/himanshu/example_app/tests/Unit/ApiAuthTest.php --filter '^.*::check_login( .*)?$' 

PHPUnit 9.5.21 #StandWithUkraine

Cannot open file "/home/himanshu/example_app/tests/Unit/ApiAuthTest.php".

 *  The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', './vendor/bin/sail php vendor/bin/phpunit /home/himanshu/example_app/tests/Unit/ApiAuthTest.php --filter '^.*::check_login( .*)?$''" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I am using Docker with Sail for testing this in Windows with the help of WSL. I setup Docker.
Here are my VSCode **settings.json**

```
{
    "better-phpunit.docker.enable": true,
    "better-phpunit.docker.paths": {
        "${workspaceFolder}": "/var/www/html/${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "better-phpunit.docker.command": "./vendor/bin/sail php",
    "better-phpunit.phpunitBinary": "vendor/bin/phpunit",
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: it will never work as you are using `sail`, so there is no path `/home/himanshu/` inside Sail container... Get inside the Sail container and do `pwd` so you know the working directory, and then use that path at the beginning instead of `/home/himanshu/`.

Comment: Hey, I added the settings.json. Please check and let me know where I'm going wrong. and inside sail container  ```sail@d75a7b243635:/var/www/html$ pwd
/var/www/html
sail@d75a7b243635:/var/www/html$ 
```

Comment: I am not sure how are you triggering the run, but if it is manual, you have to run like this `./vendor/bin/sail php vendor/bin/phpunit /var/www/html/example_app/tests/Unit/ApiAuthTest.php --filter '^.*::check_login( .*)?$'` see that I have replaced `/home/himanshu/` with `/var/www/html/`